# ASP.NET - View State being passed in URL

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

When submitting forms using the "GET" method, I am getting a huge URL containing ViewState (as well as other values I don't want).

e.g.

```
http://mysite.com/page.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKMTI5NjY4NDkzNw9kFgICAw9kFgICBw8PFgIeBFRleHQFOzx0YWJsZT48dHI%2BPHRkPlN0YXJ0aW5nPC90ZD48dGQ%2BVGhlIFRhYmxlPC90ZD48L3RyPjwvdGFibGU%2BZGRkM8TNA9%2Fwbz9egjjCUkK29Hg%2BRJE%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWAwKi9PjFBwKM54rGBgLWlM%2BbAm8w77Lt5Q4OR%2FzTWD8VQiy36FWA&days=6&displayType=dash&Button1=Back
```

You can see, there are the values I want at the very end, but I want to get rid of everything else. How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: @DOK -I understand, but I want a nice clean URL for an AJAX app

Comment: Why would you send the whole form in an AJAX call? You can control what data you pass.

Comment: So everyone who doesn't have a giant URL containing view state is inherently at risk?

Comment: There is another form on the same page..

Comment: Even better! but only one form contains the viewstate. Submit the form that isn't `runat="server"`.